# drag and drop not working on chrome - angular 7

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

I am having a problem with angular drag events , 
events dragstart , dragover , dragend.
Problem is when I use dragover on chrome is not working , is not calling on chrome  but in safari works well .
I am using angular 7

```
<div class="image"  draggable="true" *ngFor="let image of previewImages;let i = index">
<img *ngIf="image"
(dragstart)="dragStart( image , i )"
(dragover)="dragOver(i)"
(dragend)="dragEnd($event)"
(mouseover)=mouseOver($event)
[src]="image" alt="">
<a class="removeImage" (click)="removeImage(i)">X</a>
```

There's no error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of drag and drop https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ezz6jm 
And it's working fine with chrome and all other browser. Would be nice if you can share your code so we can debug more into this.

Comment: <img
    (dragstart)="dragStart( image , i )"
    (dragover)="dragOver(i)"
    (dragend)="dragEnd($event)"
    (mouseover)=mouseOver($event)
    [src]="image['url']" alt="">
    <a class="removeImage" (click)="removeImage(i)">X</a>                
this is my code into costum component              <image-uploader formControlName="image" [options]="{multiple:false}"></image-uploader>  and this is my code in image-uploader.component.ts
 dragOver(index) {
        console.log('asdas')
        console.log(index)

    }
this event is not working on chrome